# How can I go about implementing parallel computing in my Python code that can't use " if __name__=='__main__' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, pickle, genetic-algorithm

I am using MATLAB scripts that have been compiled into a Python library for use in evaluating individuals of a population in a genetic algorithm in Python. I'm really having trouble because the setup of the genetic algorithm doesn't really lend itself to using `if __name__=="__main__":` and the fitness function is a MATLAB runtime object, which cannot be pickled.

The reason I say that the structure of the code can't use `if __name__=="__main__":` is because the format looks something like this:

```
fits = []
# initialize population - needs to be parallized
for individual in population:
    fits.append(matlab_sim_function(individual))

new_fits = []
# New evaluation for loop nested in generational for loop
for generation in range(100):
    trace = []
    # evaluation for loop - this is what needs to be parallized 
    for individual in population:
        trace.append(matlab_sim_function(individual))
    new_fits.append(trace)
```

Essentially, I need to parallize that initialization of the population, then I'd need to parallize the for loop nested in the generational for loop. I'm open to any ideas on how to implement Python parallel computing in this niche scenario I'm in, whether it be possible ways to pickle the MATLAB runtime object or how to structure my code for `if __name__=="__main__":`, or even if there is a package out there that requires neither.

Comment: I don't understand what `__main__` has to do with it or why you couldn't put your code in an `if` block -- is your Tab key busted?  What does `matlab_sim_function` do?  Are you sure that parallelizing it will be useful?

Comment: For most of the python parallelization packages, they require if __name__ == "__main__", the reason it can't be implemented is because it is supposed to run through everything you need parallized one time, but getting it to work for an iterated result is a bit difficult. 
||
matlab_sim_function is the matlab runtime object that can't be pickled but evalutes the fitness for the population
||
without parallelizing the algorithm would take weeks to run, so it definitely needs this

Comment: Okay -- so you're saying you want to parallelize it by having each iteration run in its own python process (hence putting each in a `__main__` block), and the pickling is because you need a way to pass the thing into each process -- but it doesn't look like you ever use the result of `matlab_sim_function` so I'm not sure why that matters.  It's also not clear to me why you call it multiple times on the same input -- is it not a pure function?

Comment: I have used Pool (from multiprocessing import Pool) that does not require "main". Also write a method for the evaluation step, you have written it twice! :_)